# Android videoview black screen only no video output

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I have a problem playing my video from my phone. Output is a black screen, nothing happens. What should I do?

```
public class Videoview extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.plant_info);
    VideoView videoView =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/raw/kitkat.mp4");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: your code is perfect but first check your path using log and also check video file extension and if no found any extension then just put video file name no need to any extension like "kitkat.mp4" replace by "kitkat". try it